# Exclude folders from indexing in Intellij maven project using wildcard

Tags: intellij-idea

Is it possible to exclude folders from indexing using wildcard?
In my project it is just impossible to mark all /target folders as excluded. There is just too much of them.
That leads to freezes during project rebuild.

#### EDIT (thanks to @Arham)

Progress is tracked with those issues:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-127753

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-150784

For simpler things, like ignoring all target folders in project you can use:

Settings|Editor|FileTypes|Ignore files and folders

Comment: What do you mean it's impossible? Just right click the target folder and mark it as excluded.

Comment: It is impossible, because their number exceeds 300 and they appear and disappear along with usage of mvn clean. Intellij sees and marks only the top ones, but it doesn't care about the nested ones.

Comment: Size is irrelevant, just mark the root target directory. If you do this in module settings whenever target is regenerated it will be marked as excluded automatically.

Comment: So the only solution is spend all day on browsing subdirectories and marking all and every target folder in project? No batch marking or something like this?

Comment: Do you not have one root for generated files? You just need to mark the top level, and subdirectories will follow automatically.

Comment: Nope, if i've excluded the top level i would have to exclude whole project.

Comment: That is a weird structure if you have generated folders lying all over the place like that. It might be worth while to improve it. With this method yes, you'd have to do it manually. There might be settings to detect generated folders for you, but I'm not sure.

Comment: this is not a weird structure, it's a very common structure and being discussed here - https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000251070-Disable-indexing-directory-by-wildcard

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to exclude files of certain extensions.

I have configured my project on Windows to be in sync with my Linux box.

I use sftp tool provided by IntellijIdea to sync files and folders .

To configure sftp deployment goto Tools-> Deployment -> Configuration

To exclude files goto Tools- > Deployment -> Options -> Exclude items by name

This helps me in excluding certain files from getting synced from my Linux box to windows.

I guess even if your structure is not same as mine, just create a dummy deployment configuration for your existing project and that should work.